# Check for bad alloc when initializing a vector

Tags: c++, vector, heap-memory

Since I have read that every element in a vector is created on the heap, I wonder if you need to check if there is enough memory on the heap or what happens if there is not enough free space?

for example is something like this even necessary?:

```
   try {
       std::vector<T> map;
       map.pushback(t);
    } catch (const std::bad_alloc& e) {
        std::cout << "Allocation failed: " << e.what() << '\n';
    }
```

Comment: You aren't really handling the exception. The following code will go on, assuming that the operation worked. It's hard to handle `std::bad_alloc` without abandoning whatever operation you were trying to ultimately do. If you want to handle `std::bad_alloc` you will usually want to do that far from the point of failure, where something meaningful can be done.

Answer (score 4):

The scenario where you will get `std::bad_alloc` thrown is, in most situations, the scenario where you have tried to allocate too much memory, and the system has nothing left to give. In most situations, that's not a recoverable error. It might make sense to wrap your entire program in a try-catch block to maybe emit an error message (`"System ran out of memory!"`), but in most situations, it's not worth catching this error because there's not going to be a sensible recovery option for your program.

But notice that I'm hedging my language here. It all depends on the kind of application you're using. As an example, if you are writing a program that adapts itself based on how much memory is available (maybe it tries to allocate 64GB of memory, but if it can't, then it just writes/reads to temporary files instead?) it might be logical to wrap allocations like this inside a try-catch block and add the logic for the scenario where the memory allocation fails.

The difference between the scenarios where you need to catch this error, and where you don't, will become more apparent as you spend more time writing code.

Answer (score 2):

> for example is something like this even necessary?:

As stated in [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)

> If an exception is thrown (which can be due to Allocator::allocate() or element copy/move constructor/assignment), this function has no effect (strong exception guarantee).

so `push_back()` can throw such exception when reallocation occurs. If you need to check it on every call really depends on your application logic so nobody can tell you if it is necessary but you.

Answer (score 1):

> Since I have read that every element in a vector is created on the heap

`std::vector` owns an heap-allocated contiguous buffer. The elements are added to the buffer. Every element is not allocated individually.

If the buffer is full, `std::vector` automatically allocates a new bigger one and moves every element from the old one to the new one.

---

> for example is something like this even necessary?

It's probably overkill, unless you expect that `push_back` from consuming all available memory for some reason. Handling `std::bad_alloc` can be useful in some scenarios, but most of the time running out of memory is not something you want to recover from - this entirely depends on the type of program you're working on.

You also probably want to do something meaningful in your `catch` block - printing will not do anything to solve the issue.